# pandas to_numeric(…, downcast='float') losing precision

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, precision

Downcasting pandas dataframe (by columns) from float64 to float32 results in losing precision even though largest(9.761140e+02) and smallest (0.000000e+00) element is suitable for float32.

Dataset is pretty large, 55 million rows times 12 columns.
This is the mean of the particular column without downcasting (1.343987e+00) and after is this 1.224472e+00.

Same results I am getting with `np.astype()`.

Answer (score 4):

This was a pretty interesting question. I tested several dataframes starting from 1 million records to 55 million, the same size as yours, keeping `min`, `max` value similar to the ones you have.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = [], []
for idx, num in enumerate(range(1, 57, 2)):
    print(f"{idx+1}) Testing with {num} million records...")
    rows = num*(10**6)
    cols = ['col']

    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, 9.761140e+02, size=(rows, len(cols))), columns=cols)
    df['col1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], downcast='float')
    df['diff'] = df['col'] - df['col1']

    diff = df['col'].mean() - df['col1'].mean()

    x.append(num)
    y.append(diff)

plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
plt.xlabel('number of rows (millions)')
plt.ylabel('precision value lost')
plt.show()
```

Here's the plot.
[image]

Based on the plot, it seems like, after 35 million records, there is a sudden increase in loss of precision and appears to be logarithmic in nature. I haven't figured out yet why it is the way it is.

Comment: You mean logarithmic right? Cool research efforts 

Comment: That is interesting, thank you for reproducing results.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, you will always be loosing precision.

There is little you can do to avoid it, since the downcasting always happen regardless if half of the 52 bits of the float64 encode zeroes or other digits (at bit level they are not zeroes), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

The problem with the mean() function is that it probably does not handle the precision as you would expect. The answer from @tidakdiinginkan indeed shows this perfectly because adding up between 35 and 39 millions rows exceed the last digit precision and start deviating to a larger degree.

A code which will provide a better approach is using Decimal:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import decimal

x, y1, y2 = [], [], []
for idx, num in enumerate(range(1, 57, 2)):
    print(f"{idx+1}) Testing with {num} million records...")
    rows = num*(10**6)
    cols = ['col']

    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, 9.761140e+02, size=(rows, len(cols))), columns=cols)
    df['col1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], downcast='float')
    df['diff'] = df['col'] - df['col1']

    
    mean = df['col'].mean()
    mean32 = df['col1'].mean()
    diff = abs(mean - mean32)
    decmean = decimal.Decimal(df['col'].sum())/rows
    decmean32 = decimal.Decimal(float(df['col1'].sum()))/rows
    decdiff = abs(decmean - decmean32)
    
    #print("Mean:{}, Mean32:{}, MeanDec:{}, MeanDec32:{}".format(mean, mean32, decmean, decmean32))    
    x.append(num)
    y1.append(diff)
    y2.append(decdiff)

plt.plot(x, y1, 'ro', label='df.mean()')
plt.plot(x, y2, 'bo', label='Decimal(Sum(df))/num')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.title('Differences after to_numeric() float conversion with downcast')
plt.xlabel('number of rows (millions)')
plt.ylabel('precision value lost')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And comparing graphically:

[image]